How to load third-party js in Nuxt3 and use it in mounted
The reason why you don't want to configure nuxt.config.ts is because you don't want to install the js of the map on every page.
In ~/pages/test.vue
<script lang="ts" setup>
useHead({
 script: [
   {
     type: 'text/javascript',
     src: 'https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js',
   },
   {
     type: 'text/javascript',
     src: 'https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js',
   },
 ]
})

onMounted(() => {
 // How to use the global H object at this location
 let platform = new H.service.Platform({
   apikey: 'test',
 })
})

</script>

<template>
 <div>...</div>
</template>

Ask God to help me
I tried to dynamically add the map js by regularizing the route in “~/app.vue”, this method works in the case of SSG, but it doesn't work in the local dev environment

What is the error you are getting? is it that you cannot access property service of undefined? Could you try accessing H on the window object instead of global?
